# I want to sum column 1 and column 2 and replace the value of column 1 with that sum

Tags: mysql

Let's pretend we have a table:

```
ID     | col1 | col2 
1      | 23   |  4
2      | 2    |  6
```

I want to sum col1 and col2 and replace the value of col1 with that sum:

```
ID     | col1 | col2 
1      | 27   |  4
2      | 8    |  6
```

Could you tell me the query using MySQL as to how this can be done?

In my point of view the query might be:

```
Update TableName set col1 = col1 + col2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true:

```
Update TableName set col1 = col1 + col2
```

But I think you have to add another column as a `Flag` to determine if the record updated or not.

Some thing like `col3 int default 0`

```
Update TableName set col1 = col1 + col2, col3 = 1
 Where col3 = 0
```